# Make: variable fails to assign from shell call

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

```
# makefile

SHELL:=/bin/bash
PATH:=/path/to/new/programs:$(PATH)


my_var:=$(shell which program)

rule:
    echo $(my_var)
    which program

#output
$: make rule

echo 

which program
/path/to/program

# prints nothing
```

I have tried everything, and actually recall getting this to work as I was creating the makefile earlier.  It is turning into a quagmire--all I need to do is check whether an exe exists before I install it.

Comment: Use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) as `remake -x` to debug your `Makefile` and understand how `make` works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RE-WRITTEN**
(Thanks to @MadScientist for pointing out my confusion.
I thought it best to completely delete the erroneous info.)

As `$PATH` was originally exported into *make*'s environment,
*make* will ensure that it is exported into the environment of any recipe commands that it runs.
Any change made to `$PATH` in the makefile *will* make its way through to the environment of receipe commands run by *make*.

Note that this is *not* true for commands run via `$(shell …)`.
Exported variables keep the values they had when *make* started.
Any changes they suffer within the makefile are ignored as far as the external commands are concerned.

As pointed out elsewhere,
one workaround is to explicitly repeat the augmentation of `$PATH` in any `$(shell …)`

```
my_var := $(shell PATH='${PATH}' which program)
```

(Surprises me. Is this a *make* bug? Or at least a documentation bug?)

Comment: That is not true.  Any variable that was imported from the environment is automatically marked for export as well.  Modifications to those variables made in the makefile do get exported automatically.  However it is true that variable assignments made in the makefile do not get sent to `shell` functions.

Comment: @MadScientist Urk! You are right, making all the text in my answer wrong. Sigh.

Comment: This is the way GNU make has always worked.  I can't say whether it was originally intended to work this way, or if it was just an oversight.  Since it's not documented we can't say for sure.  There is a bug/enhancement request open in Savannah to change this behavior.  I don't care much myself but I am leery of changing it due to backward-compatibility issues.

Answer (score 2):

Does the explicit `which` work if you don't set the `SHELL` variable in your makefile?

Setting the `SHELL` variable only impacts recipes.  It's not used for the `$(shell ...)` function.  You can use:

```
my_var := $(shell /bin/bash -c 'which function')
```

However on my system even using the default shell works with `which`.  Maybe your system is different somehow.

Note of course `which` finds *programs*, not functions...

Comment: Ah! I will try this. did not know that.

Comment: and it looks like you are right--I am updating the path of the `SHELL` with the new binaries, but I the shell command created a child shell that was a brand new bash shell, rather than a child of the current. got it solved (next comment)

Comment: solution was to take your statement, and add: 

`$(shell /bin/bash -c 'PATH=$(my_new_bin_folder):$$PATH; which program')`

Comment: I see.  Well it would have been a lot more obvious what the problem was if you'd added the `PATH` assignment to the original makefile you showed in your question, and if you'd used the correct path to the program that which discovered (e.g., `/path/to/hew/programs/program` rather than `/path/to/program`) so it was clear that the program you're looking for was in that directory.  In general it's best to provide a short, _working_ example (cut and pasted) including error output rather than a paraphrased version which may not be accurate.

Comment: I don't think you need the `bash -c` though: the problem is not the shell, the problem is that `PATH` isn't exported.  And you can just use make's variable, like this: `$(shell PATH='$(PATH)' which program)` should work.